# How to extract multiple uima annotations of the same type with Content Analytics Studio

Tags: annotations, uima, watson-explorer

I am looking for a way in Watson Explorer Content Analytics Studio to generate multiple annotations of the same type if the text contains multiple terms in one sentence or paragraph.
I don't get past the one annotation, I can make it select all "text containers" but than still it produces one annotation.
I tried "fire all rules at this level" but that also does not give the desired result

Below some samples

> Homework will be chapters 1,2 and 4 of the book "bonjour France"
>
> Revisit paragraphs 2 and 3 of chapter 2 in the book Big History
>
> The content of chapter 1 to 3 will be part of the test
>
> For next week the homework is to read  pages 1,2 and 5 of the textbook

What I have so far is the following helpers (see screenshot)

[image]

The expected result for the first line is 3 annotations of type SinglePieceOfContent with values/features:

1. chapter 1 book "bonjour France"
2. chapter 2 book "bonjour France"
3. chapter 4 book "bonjour France"

I would like to avoid building a custom annotator, but if that is the way to go I would like to see that confirmed.

Comment: What rule type do you use: phrase or aggregate? I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do. But making a rule which produces the three annotations which you mention should be possible in WEX Studio.

Comment: @LeonardSaers we are using phrase rules and are very curious how to achieve this in WEX studio

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this, both are a bit clunky and may not work with your spevific data.

The first way is you can create multiple annotations with a single selection rule. So the brute force way to do this is to have a selector that looks something like this (high level, ignoring intervening tokens). First pick a maximum number of annotation your're going to do in a single sentence, say 5, then:

```
Selection:
find   chapter chapter? chapter? chapter? chapter? book
rule   create 5 annotations, each with limited span over just the N they refer to and add book covered text as a feature to each.
```

The second way is to use updates. Create an annotation that identifies each of the chapters and include a string feature book that is set to "default". Create another annotation that identifies book. Then create an aggregate rule like this:

```
selection:   chapter*  book
rule:    here just drag the value of book to update the feature value currently set to default.
```

No rule is actually created, it's an update. Updates can handle multiple annotations at once.

Comment: Thanks I will try this out. In the mean time we have resolved this by building a custom java annotator, but I want to check out this approach as well

Comment: I can see this work when all chapters are indeed mentioned in the text, but I am not sure how to get chapter 2 and 3 from the sentence: "study chapter 1 to 4..."